# Questions about the potential characteristics of a hypothetical Planet 9

Tags: science-based, planets, space

So, I'm writing a story. Most of the main story is set near Planet 9, which has finally been found somewhere far out in the outer solar system.

So first, I’ve been working on determining the probable characteristics of Planet 9.

In line with predictions, it’s an ice giant (a gas-rich sub-Neptune composed of an icy-rocky core with a H-He rich envelope) which is approx 7 earth masses.

The most recent article I can find on the topic from Brown and Batygin seems to predict that Planet 9’s perihelion is likely 340(+80/−70) AU, that its aphelion is likely 560(+260/-140) AU, and that the semi-major axis is 460(+160/-100) AU. Unless I am sorely misunderstanding this paper (and I could be), the numbers provided seem to be a range of numbers which they think Planet 9 could fall into.

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-3881/ac32dd/pdf

I’ll assume that the perihelion is 340 AU and that the aphelion is a bit further out - 750 AU.

The semi-major axis is half of the major axis, which is the sum of the perihelion and aphelion.

So semi-major axis = (perihelion+aphelion)/2.

The orbital eccentricity is the ratio between the difference and the sum of the perihelion and the aphelion.

So eccentricity = (aphelion - perihelion)/(aphelion + perihelion).

So, after crunching the numbers based on these initial assumptions: Its perihelion is 340 AU, its aphelion is 750 AU, its semi-major axis is 545 AU, and its orbital eccentricity is 0.38.

Now, in order to estimate the orbital period, I’ve applied Kepler’s third law of planetary motion for a quick back-of-the-box calculation. If we measure the period (T) in years and the semi-major axis (a) in AU we can use a^3 = T^2.

545 cubed is 161,878,625. The square root of that gives us an orbital period of approximately 12,723 years.

I have a few concerns. I'd like to know if my numbers are solid here, and if they are consistent with Planet 9's hypothesised characteristics given what we know.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are still quite a few people out there keeping firm belief that Planet 9 is Pluto.

Comment: Hi @the-protean, welcome here. I've shortened your text a bit, to get one question (and prevent closure..) If you don't like it, you can undo it. And I've a tip: your description reminds me of Sedna, maybe calculations can be found about that planetoid's orbit, on SE-Astronomy or elsewhere. Sedna has about the same year length, that is 11.408 earth years. https://www.google.com/search?q=sedna+orbit

Comment: I agree with other comments, please narrow the question down to one problem. You can create multiple questions to get help with your world. VTC

Comment: There's only one question that I can see here... "_are the figures I've worked out for my planet 9 compatible with real world theories on the nature of planet 9_", so I disagree with the vote to close. That said, you seem to have already done the relevant research, so it isn't really obvious to me what we can add to what you already know.

Comment: VTC: After reviewing the Q's edits I can't find a worldbuilding question. (a) Your math looks good, but checking your math isn't why we're here. That's an [astronomy.se] question. (b) The question about finding the diameter would have been better suited to the site. (c) The question about the moons is too dependent on the diameter and would have been a good follow-up question. But... as it stands... not a worldbuilding problem here. This would have been a great Q for the Sandbox.